# Flexslider and Masonry - imagesLoaded issue

Tags: jquery, flexslider, masonry

I'm trying to include a FlexSlider gallery in a Masonry jQuery layout. However, I cannot get masonry to to recognize the correct height of the FlexSlider. I know I am obviously doing something wrong with the imagesLoaded script.

I have imagesLoaded linked properly and have tried just about every combination of loading order.

How do I get FlexSlider and Masonry to work together? Thanks in advance!

Right now, I have the following script loaded in my document ready function:

```
var $container = $('#masonry'); 

        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.item',
                gutter: 25
            });
        });

    $('.multiSlide').flexslider( {
            slideshow : true,
            animation : 'slide',
            pauseOnHover: true,
            animationSpeed : 400,
            smoothHeight : true,
            directionNav: true,
            controlNav: false,
            prevText : '<span class="fa fa-caret-left"></span>',
            nextText : '<span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span>'
    });
```

Comment: I can't replicate the effect in jsfiddle. Here is the website I'm testing it out on: http://chadsherman.com/wp/

The problem is happening in Safari - but not Chrome

Comment: No, I mean that in Safari I have an overlapping issue. Here's a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/FYba6Ly.png

Edit... you deleted your comment :-(

Comment: ok.checking it. Also i see a error in firebug console, maybe thats preventing it from functioning correctly
TypeError: $container.layout is not a function.

Comment: I fixed the firebug error. It was a remnant from a different attempt to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a pretty fix, but I worked around the same issue by using setTimeout() so Flexslider fires first:

```
var $container = $('#masonry'); 

function loadMasonry(){
    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            gutter: 25
        });
    });
}

setTimeout(loadMasonry, 500);

$('.multiSlide').flexslider( {
    slideshow : true,
    animation : 'slide',
    pauseOnHover: true,
    animationSpeed : 400,
    smoothHeight : true,
    directionNav: true,
    controlNav: false,
    prevText : '<span class="fa fa-caret-left"></span>',
    nextText : '<span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span>'
});
```

I know there must be a nicer way to do this, but it seems to do the trick until I figure out what that better thing might be :P